# Android why not show my tablelayout?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

My app read a surveys questions and answers from file, and its create for this a dynamic table layout. And when my table layout is ready i would like to show this on the screen but its not working.
I have a table layout in my activity_main.xml, and i tried this to show my dynamic table on the screen:

```
tbl = dataManager.getMainTable();
```

tbl is the table layout in my xml file, and the getMainTable() method return with a TableLayout object, but its not show the table for me.

Comment: getMainTable() method return with a table layout and its has 96 children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just replacing the value of the tbl variable , but not actually showing it.

You have one table in the xml  , but another is returned in the getMainTable()

Get rid of the table in xml , then add the one returned to your container. Say you have a FrameLayout with id `mainContainer`:

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainContainer)).addView(dataManager.getMainTable(););
```